# XML parsing Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I execute SQL:

```
with demo as(
select XMLType('<items>
                  <item         id="1745212" template="Бокс            распределительный">
                         <p60226>DKC</p60226>
                        <p60227>R5PKEB2V81713B4P</p60227>
                    <p69317>Бокс распределительный</p69317>
                  </item>
                  <item id="1745213" template="Бокс     распределительный">
                    <p60226>DKC</p60226>
                    <p60227>R5PKEB2V817144P</p60227>
                    <p69317>Бокс распределительный   малый</p69317>
                    </item>
                  </items>'
                    ) xml from dual)
select   
          extractvalue(value(dt1),'/item/@id') id,
         dt2.column_value.getrootelement() property_name,
         extractValue(value(dt2),'/*') value
from 
     demo s,
     table(XMLSequence(s.xml.extract('/items/item'))) dt1,
     table(XMLSequence(s.xml.extract('/items/item/*'))) dt2
```

I waiting 6 rows return. But it return 12 rows !
For every ID this return every one  item value.
How can modify this SQL, to return only 6 rows ?
Thank you !

Comment: Please edit your post and add a desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following pl/sql.

It simulates one-to-many relationship derived from the XML hierarchy. It is better to use `XMLTable()` SQL/XML function instead of antiquated functions like `extractvalue()` and `XMLSequence()`.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=db7a7b9ce58796831151a176f32a5c9f)

**SQL**

```
with tbl as
(
    select
        XMLType(
        '<items>
    <item id="1745212" template="Бокс распределительный">
        <p60226>DKC</p60226>
        <p60227>R5PKEB2V81713B4P</p60227>
        <p69317>Бокс распределительный</p69317>
    </item>
    <item id="1745213" template="Бокс распределительный">
        <p60226>DKC</p60226>
        <p60227>R5PKEB2V817144P</p60227>
        <p69317>Бокс распределительный малый</p69317>
    </item>
</items>'
        ) xmldata
    from dual
)
select p.id, p.template, c.property_name, c.line
from   tbl,
       XMLTable('/items/item' 
               PASSING tbl.xmldata 
               COLUMNS id NUMBER PATH '@id', 
                       template VARCHAR2(100) PATH '@template', 
                       lineitem XMLType PATH './*') p,
       XMLTable('*' 
               PASSING p.lineitem
               COLUMNS property_name varchar2(20) PATH 'local-name()',
               line VARCHAR2(100) PATH '.') c;
```

**Output**

```
+----------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------------------+
|   ID     |        TEMPLATE         | PROPERTY_NAME  |             LINE             |
+----------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------------------+
| 1745212  | Бокс распределительный  | p60226         | DKC                          |
| 1745212  | Бокс распределительный  | p60227         | R5PKEB2V81713B4P             |
| 1745212  | Бокс распределительный  | p69317         | Бокс распределительный       |
| 1745213  | Бокс распределительный  | p60226         | DKC                          |
| 1745213  | Бокс распределительный  | p60227         | R5PKEB2V817144P              |
| 1745213  | Бокс распределительный  | p69317         | Бокс распределительный малый |
+----------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: You are missing the property names. Run the OP's code and you will see what is missing.

Comment: @mathguy, let's wait for a desired output.

Comment: The OP already posted a fully functional example. If you copy his code and run it, you will have the desired output - except for the fact that it includes some rows where the id from one item is mixed with the children from the other item.

Comment: @mathguy, eventually, I followed your advice

Comment: Thank you very match ! Its work well ! I have increased my experience !

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Friends, i find error in my code !
This version works well too :

```
with demo as(
select XMLType('<items>
                  <item id="1745212" template="Бокс распределительный">
                    <p60226>DKC</p60226>
                    <p60227>R5PKEB2V81713B4P</p60227>
                    <p69317>Бокс распределительный</p69317>
                  </item>
                  <item id="1745213" template="Бокс распределительный">
                    <p60226>DKC</p60226>
                    <p60227>R5PKEB2V817144P</p60227>
                    <p69317>Бокс распределительный малый</p69317>
                    </item>
                  </items>'
                    ) xml from dual)
select   
          extractvalue(value(dt1),'/item/@id') id,
          extractvalue(value(dt1),'/item/@template') template,
         dt2.column_value.getrootelement() property_name,
         extractValue(value(dt2),'/*') value
from 
     demo s,
     table(XMLSequence(s.xml.extract('/items/item'))) dt1,
     table(XMLSequence(value(dt1).extract('/item/*'))) dt2
```

Comment: Your are using deprecated XML API functions that are from the era of 10g and earlier. XMLTable() became available in 11g, and working in 12c, 18c, 19c, 21c.